# How To Subtract Two Values From a UITextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield, uilabel

Language: Swift 
Platform: IOS (iPhone 8 Build)

I have two UITextField's (Both of which are IBOutlets) Called:
priceField
startingSalary

I have a button called enterButton

What I am trying to do is subtract the value of "priceField" from the value of "startingSalary" once the user has inputted a number into them and pressed the "enterButton"

Research suggests I need to convert them from type String to type Int before they subtract, but I've sat for two days on this and I can't seem to get it right.

I also have a label called "remainingSalary:, where I want to print the result of "PriceField" - "startingSalary"

Code:

@IBAction func enterButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

```
    expensesView.text = " \(expenseField.text!)  \(priceField.text!)"
    let expense1:String = expenseField.text!
    let expense2:String = startingSalary.text!

    remainingSalary;: Int = Int(expense1)! - Int(expense2)!
```

error's
Expression resolves to an unused l-value
Expected expression

Any help would be appreciated as I can't seem to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semicolon after remainingSalary.  Also, btw, choosing to crash if expense1 or expense2 can't be converted to an Int is a bad idea.  The below prints -1.

```
let expense1:String = priceField.text ?? ""
let expense2:String = startingSalary.text ?? ""

assert( Int(expense1) != nil && Int(expense2) != nil) 
let remainingSalary: Int = (Int(expense1) ?? 0) - (Int(expense2) ?? 0)
remainingSalaryField.text = "\(remainingSalary)" // sticks the answer into a UITextField named remainingSalaryField.
```

Or you could just write this:

```
remainingSalaryField.text = "\((Int(priceField.text ?? "") ?? 0) - (Int(startingSalary.text ?? "") ?? 0))"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The above code works but it dosent fit around my scenario. I have two UITextfields, which allow for numerical user input, I need the value of one UITextField to be subtracted from the other when the user hits the enterButton, and for the result to be displayed on my lablel called "remainingSalary"

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, that's looking more like what I need, I've changed expenseField to priceField as that's what I needed. I've now inputted the value of startingSalary to 2000 and the value of priceField to 3, when I hit my button now it returns the answer "3" as opposed to "1997" as I would expect, any ideas?

Comment: I've edited my answer to match your field names exactly, even though it'd be better to be consistently named.  When I run my code using "3" for priceField's text, and "2000" for startingSalary's text, I get "-1997" as the string as I'd have expected, not "3".   So study whatever else you're doing.

Comment: I'll run it in a playground, thanks for your help on this, much appreciated.